# Multiply multiple columns (e.g. 1A*1B and 2A*2B)

Tags: r, loops, apply

I'm looking for a fast way to multipy multiple columns with a specific ending.

I have this table

| Revenue_1 | Revenue_2 | Sales_1 | Sales_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2,000 | 1,000 | 100 | 50 |
| 2,500 | 4,000 | 80 | 200 |

I want these additional columns by multiplying Revenue_N with Sales_N - For example, multiplying Revenue_1 * Sales_1 = 2,000 * 100 = 200,000

| Revenue_1 | Revenue_2 | Sales_1 | Sales_2 | Sales_1 | Sales_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2,000 | 1,000 | 100 | 50 | 200,000 | 50,000 |
| 2,500 | 4,000 | 50 | 200 | 125,000 | 800,000 |

I was playing around with for-loops or using some form of apply but coulnd't figure it out. Any help?

Comment: first, melt to long, then multiply, then cast to wide again..

Comment: @Wimpel's problem is the way to go.  Your difficulty is caused by the format of your data: it's not tidy.  Make it tidy and then life bcomes much simpler.

Comment: It's probably helpful to see what you did that didn't work so people can understand what your approach was and how to more specifically help debug it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `dat` as given reproducibly in the Note at the end we can just multiply the first two columns by the last two columns like this in base R.  Note that in the question that the new columns have the same names as other columns which is not a good idea since then you can't reference them by name so here we have used new names.  You could always change the names if you don't like the ones we used.

If there were additional columns that should not participate then instead of using `-ix` we could use `grep("Sales", names(dat))` .

We computed ix but it would be possible to simply hard code it as (1:2) and then omit the first line.

```
ix <- grep("Revenue", names(dat)) # 1:2
cbind(dat, prod = dat[ix] * dat[-ix])
##   Revenue_1 Revenue_2 Sales_1 Sales_2 prod.Revenue_1 prod.Revenue_2
## 1      2000      1000     100      50          2e+05          5e+04
## 2      2500      4000      80     200          2e+05          8e+05
```

### Note

```
dat <- structure(list(Revenue_1 = c(2000, 2500), Revenue_2 = c(1000, 
4000), Sales_1 = c(100, 80), Sales_2 = c(50, 200)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also do this with `across` in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 <- df %>%
   mutate(across(starts_with('Sales'), ~ .* get(str_replace(cur_column(), 'Sales',
        'Revenue')), .names = 'Revenue_{.col}'))
```

-output

```
df1
#  Revenue_1 Revenue_2 Sales_1 Sales_2 Revenue_Sales_1 Revenue_Sales_2
#1      2000      1000     100      50          200000           50000
#2      2500      4000      80     200          200000          800000
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Revenue_1 = c(2000L, 2500L), Revenue_2 = c(1000L, 
4000L), Sales_1 = c(100L, 80L), Sales_2 = c(50L, 200L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the base R option below

```
> cbind(df, do.call("*", rev(split.default(df, gsub("\\d", "", names(df))))))
  Revenue_1 Revenue_2 Sales_1 Sales_2 Sales_1 Sales_2
1      2000      1000     100      50  200000   50000
2      2500      4000      80     200  200000  800000
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Revenue_1 = c(2000L, 2500L), Revenue_2 = c(1000L, 
4000L), Sales_1 = c(100L, 80L), Sales_2 = c(50L, 200L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you asked for

```
df <- data.frame(Revenue_1=c(2000,2500),Revenue_2=c(1000,4000),
                 Sales_1=c(100,80),Sales_2=c(50,200))
df1 <- df %>% 
   mutate(Sales__1 = Revenue_1*Sales_1,
          Sales__2 = Revenue_2*Sales_2) %>% 
   format(scientific=F)
```

Result

```
Revenue_1 Revenue_2 Sales_1 Sales_2 Sales__1 Sales__2
1      2000      1000     100      50   200000    50000
2      2500      4000      80     200   200000   800000
```

Answer (score 0):

The tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- structure(list(Revenue_1 = c(2000, 2500), Revenue_2 = c(1000, 
4000), Sales_1 = c(100, 80), Sales_2 = c(50, 200)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")

dat %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = c(".value", "category"), names_pattern = "^(.*)_(.)$") %>% 
  mutate(Revenue_Sales = Revenue * Sales) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = category, values_from = c(Revenue, Sales, Revenue_Sales)) %>% 
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  Revenue_1 Revenue_2 Sales_1 Sales_2 Revenue_Sales_1 Revenue_Sales_2
      <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1      2000      1000     100      50          200000           50000
2      2500      4000      80     200          200000          800000
```